# Can not run apt-get update because of RethinkDB

Tags: apt, package-management

When I try to run `apt-get update` or `install` it always fails:

```
Err:10 https://download.rethinkdb.com/repository/ubuntu-focal focal InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 167.172.11.96 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://download.rethinkdb.com/repository/ubuntu-focal/dists/focal/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 167.172.11.96 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is very annoying since I can not install **anything** with apt on my system right now. Always the same error message.

I don't need anything related to RethinkDB on my system and I want to completely purge it to fix the error.

What I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge rethinkdb
```

If you need any additional information, let me know.

*EDIT:*

One install that fails for example is terraform:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main"
```

This command leads to the same error.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for the reply. I edited the question to show an example

Comment: So you added a repository. Why do you think anything is wrong with that? You'll get this warning every time until you remove that source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some repository `https://download.rethinkdb.com/repository/ubuntu-focal` mentioned it your sources list. Probably there is a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory that has a reference to that repository.

If you remove that file, the warning will go away.

Another way is to use Software & Updates app where you can also remove additional repositories.

But this warning doesn't  lead to " I can not install anything with apt on my system". You didn't mention anything in your question proving that you really can't.

Comment: Thanks. Removing `rethinkdb.list` and `rethinkdb.list.save` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` solved the problem

Comment: But it wasn't a real problem. You could install software with apt no matter that warning.

Comment: Well when running the mentioned command or `apt-get update`, it always took about 20s before timing out with the error message. It was not clear to me if the command actually was successful because the error message was its last output.